# Minimum value of quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I know that $ax^2+bx+c$ if $a < 0$ it has maximum value and we find $m = -b/2a$
but if $a>0$ it should have minimum value how can find it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, how did you determine that the minimum is at $-b/2a$ in the first case? What if you flip the parabola over?

Comment: if a < 0 it means the function will have a maximum value

Answer (score 2):

It's the same $m = \frac{-b}{2a}$. One way you can notice this is as follows: Suppose the 2nd degree polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ has $a>0$. Then multiply through by $-1$ and you'll have a 2nd degree polynomial with $a<0$. As you pointed out, the second polynomial will have minimum at $x = \frac{-b}{2a}$. This must mean the same value of $x$ gives a maximum in the first polynomial.

Comment: So for example sqrt(x^2-3x+2), it will have a minimum value and it will we sqrt(1.5) ?

Comment: The polynomial within the square root will have a minimum when $x = \frac{3}{2}$ but the minimum value of that polynomial is negative, so the function is not well-defined (for some values of x, such as $\frac{3}{2}$ the function has no value). This function will have a minimum when the polynomial within the square root equals 0. It will be helpful and rewarding to familiarize yourself with this sort of reasoning (sorry if that comes off as patronizing, but I'd hate to rob you of the opportunity to gain that power of reasoning :) ) .

Comment: Yes it would be sqrt 3rd degree

Answer (score 0):

For a more technical and deeper answer , you might want to use basic Calculus .

If you have studied some basic derivative , we know that the local maxima or local minima or the function occurs when the derivative of the of the function is $0 .$

This is true because derivative , in a sense means to figure out the slope of point in a function . And since the the function is at  minima/maxima , the slope should be $0$. $($Compare this with the time when , just before the fall , you are at the top of the roller coaster and you seem to be still at the max height$.)$

Now using some basic calculus , we find the derivative of $ax^2+bx+c$ is $2ax+b$ . Since maxima/minima occurs at $0$ , it follows that:

$$2ax+b=0\implies x=-\dfrac b{2a}$$

To figure out the whether this is a local minima/maxima , we differentiate it again to get $2a$. If $2a\gt0$ , the function is at the minima . Else if $2a\lt0$ , the function is at it's maxima.

Clearly if $a\gt 0$ , then $x=-\dfrac b{2a}$ gives us the minima , else it gives us the maxima of the function.

---

In case you are still confused , behold this :

> [image]
>
> <sub>Source : [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)</sub>

Comment: Why the downvote ?